# Different authentication backend for the django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, backend

What would be the best solution to use a different authentication backend for the Django admin site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend), which contains this quote:

> The Django admin system is tightly
>   coupled to the Django `User` object
>   described at the beginning of this
>   document. For now, the best way to
>   deal with this is to create a Django
>   `User` object for each user that exists
>   for your backend (e.g., in your LDAP
>   directory, your external SQL database,
>   etc.) You can either write a script to
>   do this in advance, or your
>   authenticate method can do it the
>   first time a user logs in.

Comment: But what will happen if a "standard" user (one who come from the django.contrib.auth.models.User) has a 'is_staff' flag. Should he be able to login into the admin interface? What I want is to avoid a privilege-escalation attack. I thinked to remove the 'is_staff' and 'is_superuser' fields from the django User table, but, by what I read it seems that another authentication backend (like one that use LDAP), will "create a Django User object for each user that exists for your backend". Still I can't figure how to avoid this, by keeping frontend user *very* far from the admin site.

Comment: @S.c. - Whether a "standard" user has `is_staff` doesn't need to have anything to do with whether they can access anything other than the Django admin site. Use permissions (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#id1) to determine who can access what. The only exception is `User` objects with `is_superuser`, who pass all permission checks.